# Ajax load function function issue

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, joomla

I have built a site using Joomla 3.

On the bottom right, there is a "contact" link that loads a contact form via ajax (using the jquery `load` function)

**The issue**

I get this error in the console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'load' of null
```

I would be very gratefull if someone can have a look, it has been driving me nuts for the past  days.

Note that the site uses the `History.js` script for ajax page navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one : you Twice load jquery
two : you must replace `jQuery`. '`$.`'

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{

});
```

or

```
function($)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me just say that the way you are doing this contact form isn't the best method. You shouldn't have to go through a separate PHP file that is located in your template folder. It should be done via a module (The Joomla way).

In your script, you're using the following which calls the contact script:

```
$('#contact').load('/templates/tmpl_yogadaviken/ajax/contact_form/contact.php');
```

What I would recommend doing is using the `JUri::root()` method, however this will require PHP, therefore it will have to be moved out of the current javascript file. For the time being, lets just test by adding this to the index.php in your template folder:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery(".contact_link, .item-108").click(function(){
         if(cont == 0){
            jQuery("#contact").load(' . JUri::root() . '"templates/tmpl_yogadaviken/ajax/contact_form/contact.php");
            cont = 1;
         }
         jQuery("#contact").fadeIn(1000);
      });
   });
');
```

Also, on Joomla 3.x, to ensure you only load jQuery once and also in noConflict mode, I would recommend using the following in your templates index.php file:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

Having multiple jQuery libraries can cause conflicts with some things.

What you can also do is use the [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) plugin which has 3 features that will most likely solve your problem:

- places jQuery libraries after MooTools calls for perfect compatibility,
- adds the noConflict() code alongside the jQuery library call,
- strips out extra jQuery and jQuery UI libraries, including the noConflict() calls added by other modules or plugins,

Hope this helps

Comment: thx for taking time to answer, I have tested your code (I changed the `"` sign jsut before `templates/tmpl_...`) but now I get this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' `. Other question, wher should I put the `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` just after the header of the template?

Comment: I have updated the code in my answr. Try adding it again however don't replace or remove anything, simply code and paste. As for the `JHtml::` code, you can add this anywhere in your index.php file, providing it goes inside `<?php ?>` tags. If this doesn't work, then I have recommended a plugin that will most likely solve the issue

Comment: If I paste your code I get this error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : `

Comment: It works now. (I still had to move the `"` sign to the bigining of the url) and define the cont variable in the `index.php` file. thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure why that error was appearing with my code, but atleast you've got it all working :)